# Comparative effectiveness of antibiotics against colonies and growing bacteria

Tags: bacteriology, antibiotics

Appropriate antibiotics usually eliminate bacteria. However are the same antibiotics as effective against bacteria that have grown to form a colony?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but some bacteria can form structures called [biofilms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biofilm), which often allow them to resist concentrations of antibiotics that are normally fatal to individual bacteria.

Comment: Usually, if there is a need to take antibiotics, it means there are *multiple* colonies of bacteria already in the body and as such the express purpose of taking antibiotics is to destroy those colonies.

Comment: I have rewritten the title and question, based on the accepted  answer. I am not a bacteriologist so, if necessary, perhaps @WYSIWYG might need to make further modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the kind of antibiotic. Some antibiotic are *[bacteriostatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteriostatic_agent)*  i.e. they primarily stop the growth while some are *[bactericidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bactericide#Bactericidal_antibiotics)* i.e. they kill the living bacterial cells. Some antibiotics can have mixed effects. Bacteriostatic antibiotics would not be very efficient in eliminating a colony.

Apart from the mechanism of action, there can be other factors that would dictate the efficacy of the antibiotic; these can all be considered under pharmacokinetics/pharmacodynamics:

- Degradation/clearance rate of antibiotic
- Rate of diffusion of antibiotic inside the bacterial colony (this rate would be less when the cells are inside a big colony compared to when they are disperse).
- Community organization and dynamics inside the colony (like user137 said in their [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48448/cant-antibiotics-destroy-colony-of-bacteria-sometimes#comment85024_48448), certain [biofilms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biofilm) can be more resistant to antibiotics)

Comment: can bacteriostatic antibiotics kill individual organisms?

Comment: @OneFace Eventually because the organisms won't be able to grow, but not directly.